# Bank conflicts with respect to word size

Tags: cuda

I read out few good articles on shared memory; but I have initial question with respect to bank conflicts
It is said that if thread 1 and thread 2 accesses word 0 from bank 0 then there is no bank conflict
but if they access different words then there will be bank conflict; but my question is how different words can reside in a single bank?
As bank 0 size is 32 bits and word size is 32 bits; there can be utmost 1 word/bank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a GPU of compute capability 2.* or 3.*, there are 32 shared memory banks; but you might well have more than 32 words (= 128B) of data in shared memory.  Each bank `b` is responsible for all the data in addresses (say) `A % nbanks == b`:

```
        +--------+---------+---------+-
Bank 0  | word 0 | word 32 | word 64 |...
        +--------+---------+---------+-
Bank 1  | word 1 | word 33 | word 65 |...
        +--------+---------+---------+-
Bank 2  | word 2 | word 34 | word 66 |...
        +--------+---------+---------+-
 ...    |  ..... |         |         |
        +--------+---------+---------+-
Bank 30 | word 30| word 62 | word 94 |...
        +--------+---------+---------+-
Bank 31 | word 31| word 63 | word 95 |...
        +--------+---------+---------+-
```

If everyone is accessing word 0, there is "broadcast" functionality for that; but if thread 0 is accessing word 0, thread 1 is accessing word 32, etc, then those accesses will be serialized.

Comment: My time spent crafting ascii art for those line printers that printed on 14.75" wide greenbar paper obviously wasn't entirely wasted.

Comment: I am really thankful to you for your time and and your effort making me explain bank conflicts.
But actually, I'm asking that as bank size is 32 bytes and word size is 32 bytes, then how can so many words be occupied in a single bank?

Comment: The bank is 32 bits "wide" - each bank is responsible for dealing with shared memory requests of one word. But it's "deeper" than one item. For instance, a Fermi has 48KB of shared memory per SM; that doesn't mean that there are 48KB/32b = 12,288 shared memory banks; there are only 32, and each one is responsible for access to 384 individual 32-bit words. So saying the "size" of the bank is 32 bits isn't quite right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It helps me understanding the concepts of shared memory banks.
I will try to work out on examples now; and will see whether I am able to understand or not.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: I found the way of accepting the answers just now, can you let me know that whether all the comments followed by the answer are part of accepted answer, or else can I accept comments also as the answer?

Comment: Just accept the answer you like. Don't worry about the comments thanks.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: If word 0 is larger than 32 bits(for example say it is of 64 bits), then I understood that 1st 32 bits of word is in Bank 0 but what about remaining 32 bits of that word 0; will it be placed consequently in Bank 0 only or it is placed in bank 1?

Comment: @JonathanDursi: rather what happens when larger than 32 bit access is made? say for example 64 bits access is made, then thread 0 will access data from bank 0 only subsequent words 'x' direction or thread 0 will access data from bank 0 and bank 1 traversing in 'y' direction?

Comment: Word 0 isn't larger than 32 bits; word 0 is exactly 32 bits long.  If each thread needs 2 words worth of data - say each are loading contiguous `double`s in an array - than the first thread would load from (say) bank 0 and bank 1, and the second would load from bank 2 and bank 3, etc.   There will be some bank conflict and waiting in this case.

Comment: @JonathanDursi:Am I understanding right? 
Access is 64 bit and thus thread 0 comes and accesses data from 2 banks bank 0 and bank 1(of column 1),then thread 1 will come and read data from bank 2 & 3, so on, lastly, thread 8 will read data from bank 15 and bank 16 now there will be roll over, and thus thread 9 will read data from bank 0 and bank 1(but different word in next column not the same word read by thread0 as it will access next column(column2)Now, thread0 was already reading data from bank0 and bank1 and in parallel thread9 also reads data from bank0 and bank1 thus 2 different-conflict

Comment: Yes.  However, *some* waiting for memory banks is inevitable in this case, as the threads are trying to pull in 8B*32 = 256 Bytes worth of data and the shared memory hardware can only provide 4B*32 = 128 Bytes in a single operation.