# Bank conflicts for strided access

Tags: cuda

I am reading CUDA_C_Programming_Guide, and in shared memory topics, I have cam across an example:
Device Compute capability: 1.0, 16 banks in shared memory

```
extern __shared__ float shared[]; 
float data = shared[BaseIndex + s * tid];
```

And in the explanation they have concluded 's' has to be odd, can anyone please help me understand what happens when `s` is even and what happens when `s` is odd?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7904494/681865) might help get you started

Comment: @talonmies: Thanks for your reply. I saw the solution posted by you for A[16][16] in shared memory for pre-fermi architecture. But I am unable to understand how banks are arranged; i.e. Row0 with bank0, row1 with bank1, and so on? or else can you explain in terms of the image posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534695/bank-conflicts-with-respect-to-word-size/13534799#comment18533925_13534799

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion of odd `s` is not easy to directly see, but if you try to derivate when bank conflict occurs (two threads tid and tid' access the same bank), assuming 32 is number of banks:

s*tid == s*tid' (mod 32)

s*tid == s*(tid + n) (mod 32) where tid' = tid + n

s*tid == s*tid + s*n (mod 32)

s*n == 0 (mod 32)

n = (32/d)*k for some k and d = gcd(s, 32)

so bank conflict will not occur when  32 is less than or equal to 32/d

and since d = gcd(s, 2^5), s has to be odd.

About your question in comments, I didn't fully get what you don't understand, but simple explanation: if two threads try to access the same bank(it means accessing two words in the same row) accesses are serialized.

Comment: :thanks for your reply. I am trying to understand. But, if you can let me know, why every time (mod 32) is written? Also I din't get how and from where 'n' came from and how equation of 'n' is derived. Does it means for thread 0, tid=0 and for thread 32, tid=0 and n=32. Is that you mean. Also I dint get how why 32 should be less than or equal to 32, if it is greater what will happen?

Comment: (mod 32) is written every time because it is modular equation (each side of equation has to be equal after modulo operation). 'n' is used as difference between two ids, equation is general so it can have many values, also your example is correct. Last thing, if 32 is greater than 32/d equation holds for more values of 'n'.

Comment: : Thanks for your reply. If we consider thread id 3 and thread id 35 then 'n' = 32, thus now if's' =1, then for thread id = 3, tid mod32 = 3 and for thread id = 35, tid mod 32 also = 3. Considering the case, when 's' = 2 then for thread id 3, tid mod32 = 6 and for thread id 70, also tid mod 32 = 6. Thus same applies when 's' is odd or even. Then why 's' needs to be odd? And if 32 is larger than 32/d, then equation holds for more values of 'n', but then what is the problem in it?

Comment: I think you are on the right way, the only thing to realize is thread block is partitioned into warps.

Comment: : Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to understand it; but if you could let me know what is the baseindex, in the original question; how to provide it, what is the syntax?

Comment: It can be anything, it is just index from which threads access array, e.g. it can depends on control variable of cycle or used for logical splitting of array into two parts.